# Listening for ReactContext variable changes in consumer component

Tags: reactjs, subscribe, react-context

I'm using ReactContext in my project and here i have a a 'consumer' component using some context variables. Everything works ok except when i try to 'listen' for changes to variable 'myName'.

```
<MyContext.Consumer>
      {context => {
        return (
          <div>Hello, {context.myName}, your title is age {...}</div>
        )
      }}
</MyContext.Consumer>
```

Whenever variable 'myName' changes i'd like to make an ajax call, get some data (like age) and display it in the component. I was looking for a way to listen to changes for 'myName', what is the best way for this? I noticed that although the component reflects the most updated 'myName', none of the React lifecycle methods are called when myName changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a `contextType` property to your class ([docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#classcontexttype)). Then you can access the updated context in lifecycle methods. I've changed an example from the docs to show this. See the `ThemedButton` component. You can comment out `static contextType` and notice that the component doesn't receive the context.

```js
const ThemeContext = React.createContext("light");

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    theme: "dark"
  };

  render() {
    // Use a Provider to pass the current theme to the tree below.
    // Any component can read it, no matter how deep it is.
    // In this example, we're passing "dark" as the current value.
    return (
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={this.state.theme}>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.state.theme === "dark"
              ? this.setState({ theme: "light" })
              : this.setState({ theme: "dark" });
          }}
        >
          Change theme
        </button>
        <Toolbar />
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

// A component in the middle doesn't have to
// pass the theme down explicitly anymore.
function Toolbar(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <ThemedButton />
    </div>
  );
}

class ThemedButton extends React.Component {
  // Assign a contextType to read the current theme context.
  // React will find the closest theme Provider above and use its value.
  // In this example, the current theme is "dark".
  static contextType = ThemeContext;

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log("Update", this.context);
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{JSON.stringify(this.context)}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

If you don't have the public class fields syntax available, you could use an analogous version of `ThemedButton.contextType = ThemeContext`.

Answer (score 1):

If you just compose your components in a way that you would example pass current context as a props to a component where you execute your fetch you would are able to use React lifecycle methods as well.

Here's a short dummy example with React hooks -implementation [CodeSandbox -example](https://codesandbox.io/s/w25n9091l).

Main points of this example,

```
// Initialize context
const context = React.createContext({ name: "" });

/**
 * My provider component which has it's own state
 * for updating existing context.
 */
const MyProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({ name: "" });
  return (
    <context.Provider value={state}>
      <input
        value={state.name}
        onChange={({ target }) => {
          console.log(target.value);
          setState({ name: target.value });
        }}
      />
      {children}
    </context.Provider>
  );
};



/**
 * Context to consume existing parent component context
 */
const MyConsumer = ({ children }) => {
  return <context.Consumer>{ctx => <MyComponent {...ctx} />}</context.Consumer>;
};

/**
 * provide values as props to your component with lifecycle-methods.
 */
const MyComponent = ({ name }) => {
  const [fetchResult, setResult] = React.useState({});
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("child updated with name: ", name);
    /**
     * Fetch some data and set it to local state
     */
    const mockFetchResult = {
      title: name + `\n${Math.random() * 1024}` // Dummy example to get some random data
    };
    setResult(mockFetchResult);
  }, [name]);
  return <p>{fetchResult.title}</p>;
};
```